# Gradle properties not being read from ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Tags: android, maven, properties, gradle

I have a similar problem as detailed here:
http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/gradle-gradle-properties-not-being-read-td4372872.html

In fact, it's the *exact* same problem - except that the solution from that thread doesn't work for me. I'm on OS/X, with an android build using gradle. The gist of what's happening is that with the following ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file:

```
uploadUsername=scottj
uploadKeyFile=/home/scottjohnson/.ssh/uploadKey
```

And the following build.gradle file:

... skipped general gradle and android-specific stuff ...

```
task checkProperties << {
  if (!hasProperty('uploadUsername')) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadUsername property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  } else if (!hasProperty('uploadKeyFile')) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find uploadKeyFile property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?")
  }
  println("***** DEBUG_jwir3: " + project.getProperty('uploadUsername'))
}
```

When I run `./gradlew checkProperties`, I get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/scottjohnson/Source/core-android/crux/build.gradle' line: 50
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':crux:checkProperties'.

  > Couldn't find uploadUsername property. Did you forget to specify it in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties?
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.072 secs

What's more interesting, if I specify that I want debug logging, I get the following:

```
mustafar:core-android scottjohnson$ ./gradlew checkProperties -d | grep properties
19:22:35.507 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
19:22:35.508 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
19:22:35.865 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /Users/scottjohnson/Source/core-android/buildSrc/gradle.properties
19:22:37.161 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
19:22:37.161 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
19:22:37.200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /Users/scottjohnson/Source/core-android/gradle.properties
19:22:37.200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Adding project properties (if not overwritten by user properties): [CORE_GROUP, CORE_VERSION_NAME, CORE_VERSION_CODE]
19:22:37.201 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /Users/scottjohnson/Source/core-android/crux/gradle.properties
```

As you can see, it's recognizing the properties in the core-android/gradle.properties file (CORE_GROUP, CORE_VERSION_NAME, and CORE_VERSION_CODE), but I don't see either of the properties from ~/.gradle/gradle.properties being pulled in.

I don't want to specify these properties in my project's gradle.properties, because they are user-specific (credentials for pushing to a private maven repository).

What am I doing wrong that is causing the gradle.properties not to be pulled in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a task action, `hasProperty` will resolve to `Task#hasProperty`. Instead use `project.hasProperty(...)`.