# ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file not being read

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

There is a similar question here: [Gradle properties not being read from ~/.gradle/gradle.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331397/gradle-properties-not-being-read-from-gradle-gradle-properties) but it does not solve my problem.

It seems to me that gradle is NOT reading my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

I have a gradle.properties file in `~/.gradle`, and it has properties needed to sign artifacts before uploading to maven central. It looks like this:

```
signing.keyId=12345678
signing.password=myPassword
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/home/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg

sonatypeUsername=me
sonatypePassword=myOtherPassword
```

When I try to build my project, it complains that there's no sonatypeUsername property, thus:

```
> Could not find property 'sonatypeUsername' on root project 'yourProject'.
```

Here's the relevant portion of my project's build.gradle:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {

            // lots of non-interesting things here

            repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
                authentication(userName: project.property("sonatypeUsername"), password: project.property("sonatypePassword"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project with debugging, here's what I see regarding properties:

```
$ ./gradlew --stacktrace --debug build

[INFO] [o.g.BuildLogger] Starting Build
[DEBUG] [o.g.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /home/me
[DEBUG] [o.g.BuildLogger] Current dir: /home/me/dev/yourProject
[DEBUG] [o.g.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
[DEBUG] [o.g.BuildLogger] Build file: null
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.b.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.b.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
[DEBUG] [o.g.a.i.a.m.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: /home/me/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.286 secs
[INFO] [o.g.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /home/me/dev/yourProject/gradle.properties
[DEBUG] [o.g.i.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
[INFO] [o.g.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/me/dev/yourProject/build.gradle'.
```

Comment: `env | grep GRADLE_USER_HOME` return anything?

Comment: yes: GRADLE_USER_HOME=/home/me

Comment: Is the `.gradle` directory at `/home/me/.gradle/`? In other words, is `HOME` also `/home/me`?

Comment: yes, and yes.  in reality, it's not "me", it's my real username.. but yes, I've set GRADLE_USER_HOME equal to HOME

Comment: Just checking... Gradle looks in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` only if set. As a hunch, can you change any dot-notation properties in that file to use CamelCase instead?

Comment: I've no `GRADLE_USER_HOME` set and just put `gradle.properties` under `$HOME/.gradle`. It all works ok.

Comment: I only added `GRADLE_USER_HOME` after trying it without, so whether I have it set or not results in the same problem.

Comment: Jeff Mixon, I did what you asked - changed the dotted properties for camel case.  Same error.  Good thought, though.

Comment: I had to `export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$HOME/.gradle`, as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124809

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem was that I made an assumption that wasn't true.  If you look at [section 14.2 of the gradle documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html), it says:

> You can place a gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable, which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle) or in your project directory.

My *incorrect* assumption was that USER_HOME just defaulted to the standard linux HOME environment variable.  This is not true.

As soon as I `export USER_HOME=$HOME` in my `~/.bashrc` everything works

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if that is really intended behavior. Are you running Linux? Pretty sure I've used just `$HOME/.gradle` in the past without issues.

Comment: Yes, I'm running Linux Mint.  It actually gets stranger... once I was able to build successfully, I removed the export statement from my ~/.bashrc and rebooted.  Now, gradle builds my project successfully whether or not USER_HOME is set.

Comment: After some conversation with gradle folks, I don't know why this happened to me, but so far, my answer stands.  Here's the conversation: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/-gradle-gradle-properties-file-not-being-read

Comment: sorry buy your link doc not available on gradle site

Comment: This worked for me even on Mac. I just had to restart Andorid Studio and global gradle.properties started showing up in it.

Comment: Heads up to anyone else who *thinks* their global `gradle.properties` isn't included in your AndroidStudio project... the global `gradle.properties` file isn't displayed when you're Project Navigator is set on "Project". If you switch it to "Android" and expand the Gradle Scripts section you'll see it there...

Comment: It is shown there, but it is not being utilized properly.  From the command line, I have the gradle daemon disabled and can verify with `--status` that it does not start up one.  From Android Studio, even though it shows that Global Properties, it still starts the daemon and leaves it sitting IDLE.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Windows and I was experiencing the same issue.  I noticed that my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file had a byte-order-marker (BOM) at the beginning and I think it had windows line endings (\r\n).  I recreated my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file by deleting it and then making a new one with vim with unix line endings (\n) with the same content as before and then it started working.  I don't know if it was the BOM, line-endings, or the combination of the two that was causing the issue, but I thought I should share this in case someone else has the same cause for this issue.

Comment: This was the only answer which actually worked for me. This is crazy. Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: This worked for me as well!

Answer (score 4):

By default, without setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, it should work. I tested it in `v3.5`.

But make sure if your are running it as the right user. For ex, if you do your `./gradlew build` using `sudo`, then `gradle.properties` in your home folder will not be picked up.

To make sure the default ***gradle user home***, you can run gradle with the `--debug` option and look out for the below line,

> [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildLogger] Gradle user home:

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution is just to simply put the gradle.properties right next to your build.gradle, that will guarantee it will be read. I realize this doesn't solve a single centralized source of common properties, but at least it's something.

Comment: the problem with that is I don't want it to be checked in to source control because it contains passwords to my private key, and to the maven central repo.  I suppose that I could add gradle.properties to my .gitignore file... but I'm holding out hope that I'm just doing something stupid that I don't see.

Comment: When even this didn't work for me, I realized I had the wrong capitalization on the property that "wasn't being read".

Answer (score 0):

> I did check Proxy Settings in Android Studio and i had No Proxy selected.
>
> I did Invalidate Cache and Restart with no luck.
>
> I added an exception in Firewall, still no luck.
>
> In project `gradle.properties` i have no proxy configurations. Its empty, only comments.

**In a previous version of Android Studio i had enabled Global Proxy Setting and it was a file stored in my user profile `%userprofile%\.gradle\gradle.properties`**

Removing proxy lines in this file, solved my issue. I had to restart Android Studio to make it work.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I myself stumbled upon this question when I was struggling with apk building via gradlew.
I tried setting Gradle_user_home earlier for the mentioned error in question, but it was of no use, below solution worked for me.

I have below configuration for gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
*distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip*
```

gradlew itself at run time downloads the correct distribution of gradle from above config (distributionUrl). Nothing else is required.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved it by using gradle binary, to build, instead of wrapper that comes with android project. You can install gradle from here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#installation

Then used system-wide gradle to build, while on project root, instead of wrapper, like ex:

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for editing you made the answer better! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made a different mistake. Why  did i set up this field in  "intelligent idea"? :)  However when i wrote correct value in this field I get correct reading gradle.properties from .gradle
[some setting in Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sPzg.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Oh I noted that the `"project property file does not exists. We continue!"` is shown because the script will search for gradle properties in different routes.

it will check both in **root/gradle.properties** and in **root/app/gradle.properties**, so it will only add the ones from the one found and display the "error" from the other one.

However in the log you can actually see the properties that were added from the read files:

```
 Adding project properties (if not overwritten by user properties): [android.nonTransitiveRClass, kotlin.code.style, org.gradle.jvmargs, android.useAndroidX]
```