# Gradle not reading gradle.properties

Tags: linux, gradle

Gradle will not read `gradle.properties`.  I guess I might have screwed up some install by running it as `sudo`.

I execute `./gradlew createDb --stacktrace --debug`

```
20:56:58.422 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
20:56:58.427 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /home/bmackey
20:56:58.428 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: /home/bmackey/Git/projectName
20:56:58.428 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
```

ERROR

```
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'buildSrc'.
    21:03:32.096 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
 No such property: some_username for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated
```

environment info

```
GRADLE_HOME=/home/bmackey/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current
GRADLE_USER_HOME=/home/bmackey
```

There is a gradle.properties in the project home directory with:

```
some_username=Defined_in_~/.gradle/gradle.properties
some_password=Defined_in_~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

This should be (and is on my Mac) overridden by

```
#/home/bmackey/.gradle/gradle.properties 
some_username=me
some_password=password
```

This same project ran fine on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.bashrc` I changed

`export GRADLE_USER_HOME="/home/bmackey"`

to

`export GRADLE_USER_HOME="/home/bmackey/.gradle"`

Restart terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sudo to run `gradlew` command, the default gradle config directory should be at `/private/var/root/.gradle`. Hope this might help.

Comment: I figured that much out.  As can be seen by the --debug output in the question, that isn't the problem.